# USB port seemingly damaged, but USB devices work when a USB extension is plugged into the seemingly damaged port

Tags: usb, windows-10, mouse

Alright, I know this sounds crazy, but this was what I experienced.

Basically this particular port, which I have been using for my mouse served me quite well. Until just a few moments ago.

At first I thought it was my mouse, then I plugged that to another port and it worked. Then I thought that the port itself was damaged. Something triggered me to use my USB extender and the mouse worked again.

What? Why? How?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the OS but in Windows the system reloads the USB hub when you plugged in a different device. Is there anything interesting in the logs around the time you had the issue?

Comment: Win 10, my bad.

Comment: Where can I view the logs tho, I can look it up.

Comment: `WinKey` + `R` to open then run box then type `eventvwr` and hit return. Look in the Windows Logs then in either Application or System.